# How to increase right spacing in Chart.js 2.6.0?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to increase the right space in the Line chart area.

I tried everything, doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: Please, add your current code here. so people can edit/suggest solutions for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to add padding to the right then you can refer the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/ymch5to6/1/

Or add below code to your options:

```
layout:{
    padding:{
    right: 100
  }
```